# Join TableViews and UITextView with dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, uistoryboard

I need to build an iOS screen whose objective is to show information about a hotel, with a "big" scroll of things.

My main problem is that I have to join a `UITextView` with a dynamic height and two lists below, each one with it own header. The lists must have a dynamic height two.

I don´t know how can I do it. I am thinking in to use `UITableView` and make each component a cell, including the lists, but I don´t know how to start. Should I do it only programatically or is it possible using storyboards?

### The mockup is below:

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI1OH.png)

### Fixing UILabel cell size (already working)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = motel.descricao;
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    //You will need to define kDefaultCellFont
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]
                        constrainedToSize:constraintSize
                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height + 30;
}
```

Comment: you want that the your UITextView change size of height and you 2 table change origin in y because you want the equal distanze between UITextView and the table every time?

Comment: Mirko, now I am using a UITableView with three cells. The firs have the UITextView (dynamic height - already working). My problem is how to put the two UITableView. It´s too strange use two cells, each one with a table inside.

Comment: for me the best way is make the UITextView inside a UIView, then under you add 2 table (if this 2 tables have every time the same size is pretty easy to do) and every time that you resize the UITextview you change the offset of 2 tables origins in y

Comment: show me the code where you resize the UITextView

Comment: The problem is that the UITableViews do not have fixed size. =( I attached the code to make the UILabel cell dynamic. It´s already working.

Comment: you want to see every time all the cells of your tables visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used inner tableview in a uitableviewcell. The problem is to manage the delegates.